# FastAPI - "TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class" with modular imports

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

When working with modular imports with FastAPI and SQLModel, I am getting the following error if I open /docs:

> **TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class**

- Python 3.10.6
- pydantic 1.10.2
- fastapi 0.85.2
- sqlmodel 0.0.8
- macOS 12.6

Here is a reproducible example.

**user.py**

```
from typing import List, TYPE_CHECKING, Optional
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from item import Item

class User(SQLModel):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    age: Optional[int]
    bought_items: List["Item"] = []
```

**item.py**

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

class Item(SQLModel):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    price: float
    name: str
```

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from user import User

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_model=User)
def main():
    return {"message": "working just fine"}
```

I followed along the tutorial from sqlmodel https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/code-structure/#make-circular-imports-work.
If I would put the models in the same file, it all works fine. As my actual models are quite complex, I need to rely on the modular imports though.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felix/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/utils.py", line 45, in get_model_definitions
    m_schema, m_definitions, m_nested_models = model_process_schema(
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 580, in pydantic.schema.model_process_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 621, in pydantic.schema.model_type_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 254, in pydantic.schema.field_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 461, in pydantic.schema.field_type_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 847, in pydantic.schema.field_singleton_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 698, in pydantic.schema.field_singleton_sub_fields_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 526, in pydantic.schema.field_type_schema
  File "pydantic/schema.py", line 921, in pydantic.schema.field_singleton_schema
  File "/Users/felix/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi_test/lib/python3.10/abc.py", line 123, in __subclasscheck__
    return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Comment: Please post the compete traceback!

Comment: Hi @AbdulNiyasPM,
I added the traceback, thanks!

Comment: Typing forward references (type hints as strings) are finicky in Python. Try typing `bought_items: "List[Item]"` instead

Comment: this doesn't solve the issues.

Comment: In my similar case, updating to Python 3.11 solved the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TL;DR

You need to call `User.update_forward_refs(Item=Item)` before the OpenAPI setup.

---

### Explanation

So, this is actually quite a bit trickier and I am not quite sure yet, why this is not mentioned in the docs. Maybe I am missing something. Anyway...

If you follow the traceback, you'll see that the error occurs because in line 921 of `pydantic.schema` in the `field_singleton_schema` function a check is performed to see if `issubclass(field_type, BaseModel)` and at that point `field_type` is not in fact a `type` instance.

A bit of debugging reveals that this occurs, when the schema for the `User` model is being generated and the `bought_items` field is being processed. At that point the annotation is processed and the type argument for `List` is still a [**forward reference**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ForwardRef) to `Item`. Meaning it is not the actual `Item` class itself. And that is what is passed to `issubclass` and causes the error.

This is a fairly common problem, when dealing with recursive or circular relationships between Pydantic models, which is why they were so kind to provide a special method just for that. It is explained in the [Postponed annotations](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/) section of the documentation. The method is `update_forward_refs` and as the name suggests, it is there to resolve forward references.

What is tricky in this case, is that you need to provide it with an updated namespace to resolve the `Item` reference. To do that you need to **actually** have the real `Item` class in scope because that is what needs to be in that namespace. Where you do it does not really matter. You could for example import `User` model into your `item` module and call it there (obviously below the definition of `Item`):

```py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

from .user import User

class Item(SQLModel):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    price: float
    name: str

User.update_forward_refs(Item=Item)
```

But that call *needs* to happen before an attempt is made to set up that schema. Thus you'll at least need to import the `item` module in your `main` module:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

from .user import User
from . import item

api = FastAPI()

@api.get("/", response_model=User)
def main():
    return {"message": "working just fine"}
```

At that point it is probably simpler to have a sub-package with just the model modules and import all of them in the `__init__.py` of that sub-package.

The reason I gave the example of putting the `User.update_forward_refs` call in below your `Item` definition is that these situations typically occur, when you actually have a circular relationship, i.e. if your `Item` class had a `users` field for example, which was typed as `list[User]`. Then you'd have to import `User` there anyway and might as well just update the references there.

In *your* specific example, you *don't* actually have any circular dependencies, so there is strictly speaking no need for the `TYPE_CHECKING` escape. You can simply do `from .item import Item` inside `user.py` and put the actual class in your annotation as `bought_items: list[Item]`. But I assume you simplified the actual use case and simply forgot to include the circular dependency.

---

Maybe I am missing something and someone else here can find a way to call `update_forward_refs` *without* the need to provide `Item` explicitly, but this way should definitely work.

Comment: Hi Daniil, thanks for the great explanation. You were right, I actually do have some circular dependencies, thus the need for the type_checking. I was aware of the update_forward_refs function, but didn't fully understood the concept behind it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone ending up here who (just like me) got the same error but couldn't resolve it using the solution above, my script looked like this. It seems that `SQLModel` relies on the `pydantic.BaseModel` so this solution also applies here.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    values: list[int, ...]

class SubModel(Model):
    values = list[int, int, int]
```

It took me a long time to realize what my mistake was, but in `SubModel` I used `=` (assignment) whereas I should have used `:` (type hint).

The strangest thing was that it did work in a docker container (Linux) but not locally (Windows). Also, mypy did not pick up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Got the error while using `from __future__ import annotations` with python 3.8. I just reorder my classes to get rid of the **future** import and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this error when importing OpenAI from langchain by looking in the error traceback at what libraries caused the import error (flexget, thinc and spacy in my case) and then running:

```
pip uninstall flexget thinc spacy
pip install langchain -U
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall the package at bottom of error then reinstall my package that was failing.