# LangChain + Hugging Face -> LangChain LLM import Error

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, langchain, huggingface

I'm trying to do the following simple code:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
import langchain
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline

model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
task = "question-answering"
```

I get the following error:

- ERROR: `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`
- LINE: `from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline`

I found the following questions (that didn't help):

1. [TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class when importing langchain in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76313568/typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class-when-importing-langchain-in-flask)
2. [FastAPI - "TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class" with modular imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346565/fastapi-typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class-with-modular-imports)
3. [TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class when using langchain in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76663778/typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class-when-using-langchain-in-azure)
4. [import langchain => Error : TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76313592/import-langchain-error-typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class)

---

I'm using Databricks with the following cluster:

- Runtime: 13.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, GPU, Scala 2.12)
- Worker & Driver type: Standard_NC21s_v3    224 GB Memory, 2 GPUs
- Libraries: [image: cluster1libraries]

Comment: Potential fix for [Databricks](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/5113#issuecomment-1558493486)

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine in one of the questions I mentioned, they also suggested this fix, I tried it and still got that error